# Open UIAlertViewController when empty " " in array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, function, button

Im trying to make a feature so when you will press a button you will open the restaurant's website and its working well, But some restaurants doesn't have a website.

```
var OnlineMenuLinks = ["https://static.wixstatic.com/media/ed1b11_59335d19e484482e8c0dc9ef0caee605~mv2.jpg/v1/fill/w_708,h_992,al_c,q_85/ed1b11_59335d19e484482e8c0dc9ef0caee605~mv2.jpg","","","http://stackoverflow.com/"]

    @IBAction func OpenOnline(_ sender: Any) {

            let url = URL(string: OnlineLinks[MyIndex])!
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            } else {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
            }
        }
```

The links are opened currently and everything is good.
Though i want when there is an empty `""`in the array an UIAlertController will show up and say for example "this restaurant has no website." is it possible?

Thank you for your help ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var onlineMenuLinks = ["https://static.wixstatic.com/media/ed1b11_59335d19e484482e8c0dc9ef0caee605~mv2.jpg/v1/fill/w_708,h_992,al_c,q_85/ed1b11_59335d19e484482e8c0dc9ef0caee605~mv2.jpg","","","http://stackoverflow.com/"]

let myIndex: Int = 0

func openOnline(_ sender: Any) {
    let string = onlineMenuLinks[myIndex]
    if string.characters.count > 0, let url = URL(string: string), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
        // valid URL
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
        }
    } else {
        // invalid URL
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "This restaurant has no website.", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes It is possible

```
      func open(_ url: URL?) {
        if let url = url {
            if #available(iOS 10, *) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:],completionHandler: { (success) in
                    print("Open Safari \(success)")
                })
            } else {
                let success = UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
                print("Open Safari \(success)")
            }
        }else{

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Empty!", message: "This restaurant has no website.", preferredStyle: .alert)

            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)

            alert.addAction(okAction)
            present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you ! i used @iWheelBuy Code to open the links but i used your UIAlertController so i can dismiss the message :)

Answer (score 0):

Do not check for the string validity. In your case, an error should be displayed every time the `URL` isn't valid (an empty `String` doesn't produce a valid `URL` instance).

```
var OnlineMenuLinks = ["https://static.wixstatic.com/media/ed1b11_59335d19e484482e8c0dc9ef0caee605~mv2.jpg/v1/fill/w_708,h_992,al_c,q_85/ed1b11_59335d19e484482e8c0dc9ef0caee605~mv2.jpg","","","http://stackoverflow.com/"]

@IBAction func OpenOnline(_ sender: Any) {

    if let url = URL(string: OnlineLinks[MyIndex]) {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
        }
    } else {
        // show error
    }
}
```

A check over the array count might be needed in case `MyIndex` exceeds the array length.

```
guard OnlineLinks.count > MyIndex else {
    // throw an error
}
```